# Open office regular expression remove the first two directory only

Tags: regex

I want to search and replace csv file using Open office calc. I want to remove every directory name of the image path.

For example:

This is the path to the image `abc.jpg`:

```
/images/upload/abc.jpg
```

Replace with:

```
/abc.jpg
```

I want to remove the directory name and keep only the jpg file name with the forward slash (`/`).

What is the regex command to do that?

I tried:

Find:

```
/*/*/*.jpg
```

Replace with:

```
/*.jpg
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like you should start with a regex tutorial. `*` doesn't mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
^.*(\/.*?\.jpg)$
```

Replacement string:

```
$1
```

Use `$1` or `\1` based on your tool.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gH7pG6/4)

Comment: thanks, but should I add '.jpg' in the regex, ^.*(\/.*)$.jpg cause I don't want to replace any other file but jpg or image file only